# Installing TheRubyRacer gem on fedora 20 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compiler-errors, bundler, fedora

I am working on a project, that needs therubyracer. When I do a bundle install I get the following error message when the bundler tries to install therubyracer.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for v8.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
g++ -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -m32 -o init.o -c init.cc
g++ -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -m32 -o signature.o -c signature.cc
g++ -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -m32 -o exception.o -c exception.cc
g++ -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -m32 -o primitive.o -c primitive.cc
g++ -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -m32 -o context.o -c context.cc
In file included from context.cc:1:0:
context.cc: In static member function ‘static VALUE rr::Context::SetEmbedderData(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
context.cc:81:23: error: ‘class v8::Context’ has no member named ‘SetEmbedderData’
   Void(Context(self)->SetEmbedderData(NUM2INT(index), Value(data)));
                       ^
rr.h:33:20: note: in definition of macro ‘Void’
 #define Void(expr) expr; return Qnil;
                    ^
context.cc: In static member function ‘static VALUE rr::Context::GetEmbedderData(VALUE, VALUE)’:
context.cc:85:23: error: ‘class v8::Context’ has no member named ‘GetEmbedderData’
   Void(Context(self)->GetEmbedderData(NUM2INT(index)));
                       ^
rr.h:33:20: note: in definition of macro ‘Void’
 #define Void(expr) expr; return Qnil;
                    ^
make: *** [context.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/anupam/.gem/ruby/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/anupam/.gem/ruby/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1' or without the version, it still fails.

I am new to ruby so I don't really understand what is going on or why it is failing.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Try the following: `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1' -- --with-system-v8`

Comment: Did there was no debug messages. Just a straight up error message without any hints.[anupam@localhost therubyracer-0.12.1]$ gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1' -- --with-system-v8
Building native extensions with: '--with-system-v8'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    

Gem files will remain installed in /home/anupam/.gem/ruby/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Fedora 24 x64 and the `sudo dnf -y install gcc-c++` resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I removed all gems.

Uninstalled ruby

Reinstalled ruby ruby-devel

Installed ruby and ruby-devel and install therubyracer and libv8 using yum NOT gem.

Then I ran bundle install and gem used the already installed gems that yum installed.

Thank god for fedora maintainers! You guys are awesome

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds dumb but I had the exact problem and it seems I lacked the package gcc-c++. Thought already had them. `yum install gcc-c++` did the trick